# Problema com Binding e CaretIndex

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho uma Lista com Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="GridLista" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="20" 
                     Margin="5" 
                     Grid.RowSpan="17" 
                     Grid.Row="3"
                     CanUserAddRows="False"
                     CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lista}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model, Mode = TwoWay}"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
              >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.1*" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Header="Código"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.9*" Binding="{Binding Nome}" Header="Nome Operador"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Após clicar em uma das linhas, todos os textbox são preenchidos, abaixo um deles:

```
<TextBox Name="textOperadorNome" Text = "{Binding Model.Nome, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CharacterCasing="Upper" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"  Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4"/>
```

Até ai nenhum problema, tudo funcionando.

Meu problema é: sempre que ele é preenchido depois de ser clicado na tabela, o textbox ganha o foco e ao invez dele colocar o cursor no final do texto, ele coloca no começo, tem alguma forma de corrigir esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver esta questão de duas maneiras.

---

### Solução A

Você pode adicionar um valor default para a propriedade `CaretIndex`, conforme foi feito abaixo.

```
<TextBox Name="textOperadorNome" Text = "{Binding Model.Nome, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CaretIndex="1000" CharacterCasing="Upper" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"  Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4"/>
```

Para este código deve-se observar três detalhes.

**1 -** A propriedade `CaretIndex` deve ser definida após a definição do valor do `Text`, caso o contrário a solução não irá funcionar.

**2 -** O valor aplicado ao `CaretIndex` deve ser alto, pois ele define a posição final do seu cursor e caso seja inferior à quantidade de caracters do seu `TextBox`, o cursor não ficará ao final do texto conforme desejado.

**3 -** Caso o usuário clique no `TextBox` e coloque o cursor em qualquer posição que não seja o fim, muito provavelmente ao se clicar o *grid* para fazer um novo carregamento no `TextBox`, o cursor não ficará no fim, pois a ação anterior alterou o `CaretIntex` do `TextBox` no processo, não sendo mais o definido inicialmente.

---

### Solução B

Você pode adicionar uma ação ao evento `GotFocus`, de modo a executar uma função que irá definir o seu `CaretIndex` com o valor do tamanho do seu texto.

Segue abaixo o código do `TextBox` com o evento:

```
<TextBox Name="textOperadorNome" Text = "{Binding Model.Nome, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" GotFocus="TextOperadorNome_GotFocus" CharacterCasing="Upper" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"  Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4"/>
```

Segue abaixo a definição da execução do evento no *Code Behind*:

```
private void TextOperadorNome_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textOperadorNome.CaretIndex = textOperadorNome.Text.Length;
}
```

---

**Observação**: A solução B é mais confiável e vai garantir que sempre se chegue no resultado desejado!

Caso queira verificar, existe uma outra pergunta na comunidade sobre este assunto no link: [Set the caret cursor position to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888907/set-the-caret-cursor-position-to-the-end-of-the-string-value-wpf-textbox).